if Jenkins is setup as service on window, Can we start it as Application/process too via Java -jar jenkins.war?
We have a server having multiple users, One user who have Admin rights he setup Jenkins as a service and it's working perfectly fine.
the directory of jenkins is

C://Users/serviceUser/AppData/local/jenkins

No I came up with a situation where we have to execute an exe file and to interact with GUI it is recommended by application offical docs that 'Disable' jenkins using as a Service and Execute it as application/process via java -jar jenkins.war command.
No My question is as I also have admin right, So Should I have to download Jenkins war file in seprate user or root folder? or We can Use 'ServiceUser' path to start jenkins via Java -jar jenkins.war??
Note: I need clarification does it require different setup for both to set jenkins as a service and via jenkins.war files? OR both can access via same setup?
